# Java's ProcessBuilder: possible to send console output to error, file output to the inputStream?

Tags: java, inputstream, processbuilder

I'm using Java's `ProcessBuilder`, and it is working great!  *(Shocking, I know.  But just wait...)*

Setup and Goal: I've got a binary app `nrsc5` wrapped by a ProcessBuilder, which

1. Sends the regular output *that would normally show on the console* but instead is read by the java wrapper via `getInputStream()` and parsed into lines.  Excellent.
2. It **also** is continually writing to a binary file TEMP.WAV
3. Every so often my wrapper java app looks at the TEMP.WAV and reads some chunk of it.

This **works but is a monster and is horribly inefficient**.  And, I just found out that yes, the nrsc5 app can write that WAV file to standard output the same as lots of other linux apps!  `... -o - ...` (output file is a dash means "write to stdout")

This is excellent! No more WAV file!  But... the console lines get all mushed together with the binary output, which is verybad.

**Is there a way to say "all the text goes to one place like the error stream, and all the binary goes to another place like the regular input stream"?**

Comment: Most tools that can write their output to stdout have the ability to send diagnostic output to stderr.  Are you certain the nrsc5 program doesn’t have such an option?  `-o -` is useless without it, as you are discovering.

Comment: @VGR I asked, we shall see!  https://github.com/theori-io/nrsc5/issues/275

Comment: Turns out I had it all backwards, so I'm good. The log was already going to err.